# LEFT JOIN creates multiple rows, GROUP BY or DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

So I'm trying to LEFT JOIN a table to check if there's a running compaign on a shop, but rows seems to repeat if there's a match.

I tried to use DISTINCT and GROUP BY, but it does not behave like I want it to.

```
SELECT
    s.id AS ShopID,
    s.name,
    si.id AS shop_item_id,
    si.item_price,
    p.cat_id AS category_id,
    c.campaign_desc,
    c.campaign_type_id,
    c.shop_id AS campaign_shop_id

FROM
    shop_item si 

    JOIN
        shop s ON 
        s.id = si.shop_id
    JOIN
         product p ON 
         si.product_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN 
        campaign_category cc ON 
        cc.category_id = p.cat_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        campaign c ON 
        c.id = cc.campaign_id AND
        c.shop_id = si.shop_id
WHERE
    si.`product_id` = 299 AND
    s.`active_shop` = 1

ORDER BY
    si.`item_price`,
    ShopID,
    c.campaign_desc DESC
```

[image]

But if I add

```
GROUP BY ShopID
```

it returns this

[image]

So suddenly "Black Friday" is missing on the first shop "Shop 1". I have also tried DISTINCT without any luck and I'm kinda confused right now. What am I missing?

Best Regards
John

Comment: non-aggregated columns like `c.campaign_desc` will be undeterministic if using a `GROUP BY` clause. If `only_full_group_by` mode is enabled (default behaviour in newer MySQL versions), this query will throw out error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use group by cluase with max aggregation, as your duplicate column value produce null value for description, campeign_id and shop_id, these can be handled using max, but if you share your table structure then it would be easy to identify why it produce duplicate records and what could be the best solution

```
SELECT
    s.id AS ShopID,
    s.name,
    si.id AS shop_item_id,
    si.item_price,
    p.cat_id AS category_id,
    max(c.campaign_desc) as desc,
    max(c.campaign_type_id) as campaign_type_id,
    max(c.shop_id) AS campaign_shop_id

FROM
    shop_item si 

    JOIN
        shop s ON 
        s.id = si.shop_id
    JOIN
         product p ON 
         si.product_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN 
        campaign_category cc ON 
        cc.category_id = p.cat_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        campaign c ON 
        c.id = cc.campaign_id AND
        c.shop_id = si.shop_id
WHERE
    si.`product_id` = 299 AND
    s.`active_shop` = 1
group by s.id,
    s.name,
    si.id ,
    si.item_price
ORDER BY
    si.`item_price`,
    ShopID,
    c.campaign_desc DESC
```